# Using Huey with Django: How to keep run_huey command running?

Tags: python-huey

I'm using Django on Ubuntu 18.04.

I've got everything set up. And I type `python manage.py run_huey` in the server (through an SSH connection) to start huey, and it works.

However this is done through the command line through SSH and it will shut off when I close the SSH connection.

How do I keep `run_huey` running so that it will stay active at all times? Furthermore, after a system reboot, how do I get `run_huey` to automatically start?

Answer (score 0):

You may explore supervisorctl utility for ubuntu, it keeps process running and can log into file and any other features. Google it.